# Basic Code error

Tags: java

this is the basic program which im trying

```
public class keyboardinput {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
       int a ;
       System.out.println ("enter the text");
       a =  (int) System.in.read();
       System.out.println ("the entered value is :"+a );
    }
}
```

when executed, its showing the below response

**enter the text**

**1**

**the entered value is :49**

when i enter 1, why is not showing the entered value is 1

Could you please let me know why the output is showing equivalent asci values instead of what i entered in input

Comment: You input an ASCII character: 1. It's value (when cast to int) is 49. Similarly, you'll get 50 when you input 2, 32 when input space, etc.

Comment: Hint: the ASCII code for '1' is 49.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot just cast from a byte to an int, as you are doing here:

```
a =  (int) System.in.read();
```

`System.in.read()` returns an integer, but the result will be the ASCII code for the character `1`, which is 49.

I suggest using a Scanner:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
a = s.nextInt();
```

Comment: Use of scanner recommended is good! +1 for that, but `System.in.read()` returns an integer as far as i know, not a byte!

Comment: Yes indeed you are correct. Should have looked more carefully. I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`49` is ASCII code of symbol `1` which you are explicitly case to `int`. To read `int` value use something like this:

```
    try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        a = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
        System.out.println("the entered value is :" + a);
    }
```